# Destructure and Rename Optional parameters in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I currently have below in JS but want to convert to TS and make both arguments optional along with keeping renaming

```
const sortPositionAscending = ({ position: a }, { position: b }) => {
  if (a < b) return -1
  if (a > b) return 1
  return 0
}
```

because I'll be using it for

```
const sortPositionDescending = (...args) =>
  sortPositionAscending(...args) * -1
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to provide a type and default value for each argument.

```
const sortPositionAscending = (
  { position: a }: { position: number } = { position: 0 },
  { position: b }: { position: number } = { position: 0 },
) => {
  if (a < b) return -1
  if (a > b) return 1
  return 0
}
```